# How to adjust the right hand toc depth in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tableofcontents

I am building a HTML page with `jupyter-book build . --all` und want to view every single headline I wrote before in a Jupyter Notebook with `#`, `##`, `###` and so on.
Is it possible to adjust the right hand table of content depth, named as **Content**, in Jupyter Notebook?

I haven't found any hint in the documentation.

It only shows up to a depth of two and shows deeper levels only if I scroll to a part of the site, where an entry of a deeper level exists.

I'm generating my `_toc.yml` with

```
jupyter-book toc from-project . --extension .ipynb -e .md -f jb-book > _toc.yml
```

This is the generatet content of `_toc.yml`

```
format: jb-book
root: index
chapters:
- file: 000_001_notebooks
- file: 000_002_markdown
- file: 000_003_markdown-notebooks
- file: 001_000_print
- file: 001_001_variables
- file: 900_000_matplotlib
```

Comment: Have you tried the `:depth:` or `:maxdepth:` options? https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/structure/configure.html#limit-the-depth-of-the-in-page-contents (Documentation contradicts itself a little here, can't tell which is correct.)

Comment: @NickODell Yes, I've tried `:depth:` but this generates a toc inside the page. I want to adjust the right hand toc of the generated HTML content of the single page.